# Unable to add new records to Sandbox

Tags: sandbox, data, file-storage, data-storage, storage-limit

In my storage information I see :

[image]

[image]

I am unable to create any new record as it says the data storage limit has exceed.

What I did - I queried all the contentDocument, Attachment and deleted them which brought down the size from 46 GB to 42 GB. But I am not able to figure out that how content is 42.7 GB now? How can I free up the space in my org?

Thanks

I see that in my org user have uploaded lot of documents in "Files". How do I delete these files using Dataloader, what object it is?

[image]

Comment: Have you emptied the Recycle Bin?

Comment: Yes, I deleted from there too. That got me to 42.7 from 46. Do you know what are chatter files?

Comment: if there are managed packages installed , uninstall them too ! some managed packages occupy a lot of space

Comment: @ankit.sehgal packages don't directly use space. It's content that's the problem.

Comment: @sfdcfox: What you guys think? I am really wondering how the org has so much of data and where is it. I Can't figure out yet.

Comment: I found the place where there is lot of file stored. I see that in my org user have uploaded lot of documents in "Files". How do I delete these files using Dataloader, what object it is?

Comment: @sfdcfox I found the place where there is lot of file stored. I see that in my org user have uploaded lot of documents in "Files". How do I delete these files using Dataloader, what object it is?

Comment: `ContentVersion` is your place to go

Comment: Hi , I found that these files are privately shared so it does not show up when I query the ids of contentdocument . When I changed the shared setting of one of file to public , I was able to view the record using SOQL in the workbench

Comment: I have 1000s of files all privately shared which I want to delete . How can I do that?